# Pulling/copying specific shapefile from subfolders using ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I'm trying to copy only line shapefiles from a folder that contains sub-folders and put them all into a new geodatabase. So far, it runs fine and creates the geodatabase, but when I go check, the folder is empty. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy


arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/path/PPA"

out = "name.gdb"
out_exists = arcpy.Exists(out)
if out_exists:
    arcpy.Delete_management(out)

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:/path/morepath", "test.gdb")
wslist = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
print(wslist)
for ws in wslist:
    print(ws)
    linelist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type="line")
    for line in linelist:
        linedesc = arcpy.Describe(line)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(line, "C:/path/morepath/name.gdb/" + ("name_" + linedesc.basename))
print("done")
```

Any ideas as to why it isn't working?

Comment: Best practice is to use `os.path.join()` instead of string math. Debugging the name *before* executing the ArcPy function will usually help. You should always get an error trying to add a table with a period in the name (you cannot place a shapefile in a file geodatabase, only convert a shapefile to a FGDB table)

Comment: What is the output from your print statements when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: You have forgotten to change your workspace into the subfolder before calling ListWorkspaces(). There is a new function in the da module arcpy.da.Walk() that walks the tree of workspaces and geodatabases that will work better than os.walk(). The walk function returns full paths so you don't need to traverse the workspace folders yourself. [help doc](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @KimO, this is best handled by the da module. Walk

```
import os
import fnmatch
import arcpy

topdir = 'my/top/directory'
search = '*string*in*file*.shp'

shp_lst = []
for root, dirs, files in arcpy.da.Walk(topdir, type = 'Polyline'): #looked like you were looking for just lines, if you remove the type - it defaults to all
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, search):
        shp_lst.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for shp in shp_lst:
    #do something with the shape
    outputdb = 'c:/somedb/gdb'
    outpath = os.path.join(outputdb, os.path.splitext(shp)[0])
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shp, outpath)
```

Fixed some errors pointed out by @BERA

Comment: You should probably replace output in last line with something like `os.path.join(outputdb, os.path.splitext(shp)[0])` and add `outputdb=r'C:\somedatabase.gdb'`. Or each fc will overwrite previous

Comment: I think to make this code truly bomb proof you need to [validate](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/validatetablename.htm) the dataset name against the workspace you are copying into as mentioned by @Vince above. You cannot assume the shapefile name and it rarely does, conforms to geodatabase standards.

Comment: @Hornbydd that's a neat tool, I'm running 10.6 and it doesn't seem to be available.  I'm not sure what version of Arc OP is running - any idea what version that hit?

Comment: That arcpy function has been around for a few years so even fairly old versions of arcmap can run it.